# Insert data into extended table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I'm new to Postgres and learning how to create functions. I try to insert data into extended table using a single function, so I decided to use the function `currval(regclass)`. Is it possible, or should I find different ways to do so?

PostgreSQL 9.6

My code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_plot_process(
duration INTEGER,
deadline_date DATE,
description TEXT,
status PROCESS_STATUS,
estimation_time INTERVAL,
start_date DATE
) RETURNS VOID AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO processes(DURATION, DEADLINE_DATE, DESCRIPTION, STATUS, ESTIMATION_TIME, START_DATE) 
    VALUES(duration, deadline_date, description, status, estimation_time, start_date);
    INSERT INTO plot_process(MAIN_PROCESS_ID) VALUES(currval('processes_main_process_id_seq'));
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?